# How to format JSON properly when I save to file using Python Pandas?

Tags: python, json, pandas

A source JSON file looks like this:

```
{
 "Ke1" : [
   {
    "Key2" : [
   { xxx
}
]
}
]
}
```

When I update the file using `df=pd.DataFrame(data) df.to_json(new_file)` it saves as:

```
{"Key1":{"0":{"Key2":[{ xxx }]}}}
```

I need it to be saved in original format. Without id 0 and as a list of Key2 (the second bracket was `[` and it turned to `{` ). How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_normalize`:

```
import pandas as pd

data={
    "Ke1": [{
            "Key2": [{
                    "we": "wewe"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
df=pd.json_normalize(data)
df.to_json(orient="records", lines=True)
```

Output:

```
{"Ke1":[{"Key2":[{"we":"wewe"}]}]}
```

Comment: I changed #df=pd.DataFrame(data) to 
df=pd.json_normalize(data). The file saved empty.